# How to turn off the computer's built-in speaker

Tags: motherboard, window, speakers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Only to Turn off builtin speakers?](https://superuser.com/questions/40099/only-to-turn-off-builtin-speakers)

I have a Dell computer and I use ear phones to listen to music.
Sometimes I turn on the music and forget to plug my ear phones in and everyone in the room gets disturbed with the music.

Is there any way that if I don't plug anything in then I won't hear anything from the computer's built-in speaker?

Comment: Do you have Realtek HD audio? This would be a red speaker icon in your hidden icons near the clock.

Comment: yes the audio ios REaltek , speaker icon is there but i disable that then i can't even listen from headphones as well